# Fully javascript generated site seo

Tags: javascript, seo

The index.html includes only a div where all the html generated by Javascript.
I know that one of the ways is to redirect search bots to an onother html. I read this on an old post and i want to know if is the best way and one or two tips for this.(not how to redirect)

The site is build in Tumult Hype so i cant place content on html.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the search bot to a diffrent document then this is considered cloaking and may harm your ranking in google.

Yes, google is able to execute JS. But you should not dynamically generate the content on your site, it will hurt your rankings. One could use some kind of prerender.

Edit: of course you can dynamically generate content, but the main content should not be using dynamic javascript.